# Delay in UITextFieldDelegate event

Tags: ios, uitextfield, uitextfielddelegate

This is a strange problem but I am perplexed on how to solve this - I have a `UITableView` that has custom UITableViewCells. Each `UITableViewCell` has two `UITextFields` and each `UITextField` is linked to a delegate that processes the `textFieldDidEndEditing` event. This works perfectly except in one instance.

**Problem**

The screen also has a 'Save' button and the problem arises when the user edits a `UITextField` and directly clicks the 'Save' button without clicking elsewhere in the screen. In such an event, the `saveAction` method is invoked before the `textFieldDidEndEditing` event and as a result the last edit of the user is lost.

I tried to debug using NSLog statements and found that while the `textFieldDidEndEditing` is indeed getting called, it is called after the `saveAction` event.

I thought about calling the `textFieldDidEndEditing` event from `saveAction` but that didnt make sense as I would have no idea about which `UITextField` is being edited.

Any suggestions are very much appreciated.

Comment: Did you try sending the text field -resignFirstResponder inside -saveAction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could make a note of the text field that is active when the –textFieldDidBeginEditing: delegate method is called in your view controller

have an assigned property that points to the active text field and then in -saveAction send it -resignFirstResponder.

header:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) UITextField * editingTextField;
```

m file:

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField{
self.editingTextField = textField;
}

-saveAction{
if(self.editingTextField)
    [self.editingTextField resignFirstResponder];

 //continue implementation
}
```